# How to get a mongodb query to frontend code

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb

I'm trying to query a MongoDB database and then display it to the frontend code/page.

Here's what I got so far. Note, it does sucessfully console.log() the search results on the backend just not on the frontend.

Backend File

```
export async function searching() {
    let output = "";
    const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    const url = "mongodb+srv://[protected..]";
    await mongo.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true}, (err, client) => {       
        const db = client.db('domains')
        const collection = db.collection('domains')
        collection.find().toArray((err_again, items) => {
            output = items
            console.log(output)
            return output
        })
    })
}
```

Frontend

```
export async function button2_click(event) {
    let output = await searching()
    console.log(output)
}
```

Note I'm doing this in Wix code so some of the synctax front-end syntax might be different.

The "console.log(output)" gets an undefined response.

When I console log the backend file the "console.log(output)" successfully outputs the array, but it's now showing on the frontend console.

Please help I've been spending hours on this with no luck. THANK YOU!

Answer (score 1):

I was able to figure this out so I figured I would post the answer here:

```
export async function findRecord(database, sub_db, query) {
    let output = "";
    const mongo = require('mongodb').MongoClient
    const url = "mongodb+srv://...";
    const client = await mongo.connect(url, {useNewUrlParser: true,useUnifiedTopology: true});

    const db = client.db(database)
    const collection = db.collection(sub_db)
    const items = await collection.find(query).toArray();
    client.close()
    return items;
}
```